# python requests module doesn't load response content

Tags: python, module, python-requests

i'm have some problems using the python requests module to doctest my application and wasn't able to get it until now. 
Sometimes it happens that a response body is missing. But when i look at the network request/response with ngrep, i can see the response body. So it seems that it is ignored by a python module. This makes my doctests very unstable and thereby useless.

```
>>> response = requests.get('/api/v1/profile/%s/affiliations' % urllib.quote(profileId1))
>>> affiliations = response.json
>>> pprint(affiliations)
[{u'name': u'Affiliation A'},
 {u'name': u'Affiliation B'}]

Failed example:
    pprint(affiliations)
Differences (ndiff with -expected +actual):
    + None
    - [{u'name': u'Affiliation A'},
    -  {u'name': u'Affiliation B'}]
```

The ngrep trace looks like this:

```
###########
T 127.0.0.1:62252 -> 127.0.0.1:9000 [AP]
GET /api/v1/profile/4fde28e80364cb830f649ee1/affiliations HTTP/1.1.
Host: localhost:9000.
Connection: close.
Accept-Encoding: identity, deflate, compress, gzip.
Accept: application/json.
User-Agent: python-requests/0.13.0.
.

##
T 127.0.0.1:9000 -> 127.0.0.1:62252 [AP]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK.
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8.
Content-Length: 63.
.
[{"name":"Affiliation A"},{"name":"Affiliation B"}]
###########
```

Comment: Hello. Does this still happen with a recent version of requests (might have been a bug) ? If so, does it happen only in doctests, or also with a normal script execution ?

Comment: Can't say. We threw the whole python doctests away and implemented a java library instead. The whole project was a java project so the integration was even better.